# Best way to encrypt and decrypt persisted data in Node.JS?

Tags: encryption, node.js

I'm writing a Node.JS application that will store chat logs to a datastore (i.e. MongoDB), along with some other user information.  I'm already using bcrypt to store salted hashes for user passwords, so I'm covered there.

What the best method of encrypting persisted data?  I'm talking about sensitive user data such as phone numbers, and the chat logs.  If my database gets compromised, I don't want this information being usable.

I do need two-way encryption/decryption, however, because I need to be able to use the plain-text values (i.e. the phone numbers are for [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), the chat logs are for users to see their old messages).

I'm looking into node-crypto but I haven't been able to find any examples of doing this in a performant/realtime fashion.

**UPDATE**: I should've mentioned that the chat "logs" are actually full conversations that get pushed to "rooms" in real-time when users join them (i.e. they can see the entire chat history, or at least a subset of it).  So, I'd need to be able to encrypt and decrypt on the fly pretty quickly (if not in real-time, at least with some sort of worker process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is use [`require('crypto')`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/crypto.html).

You will however need to port it to the clientside. Good luck with that. (Shouldn't be too hard with browserify)

Comment: Hmm, what's better, to use it server-side only (and send the plaintext to clients but using https) or to use it on the client as well, with browserify?

Comment: Looks like there are actually decent JS implementations available:  http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Answer (score 0):

Do it all server side, if you do it client side you will need to expose your encryption keys.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Using a public-key scheme or a Diffie-helman scheme with PBKDF'ed keys would allow browser clients to download password-protected private keys and encrypted data and decrypt entirely on the client-side.  The unfortunate thing here is figuring out a way to "store" the private key locally.  It'd be okay to use something like PersistJS, so that private keys are only exposed to the owners, but making sure they're cleaned up after a session expires becomes the tricky part.

Comment: They could still be accessed by writing the key variable to the console in something like firebug. If they are stored in browser storage they can also be queried.

Comment: Sure, but it's okay if a user sees their own private key, just like you can `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and see your private key.